# JS, PHP, and MySQL to get large data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am using Ajax to send query to PHP server, which then run the SQL query to get data. Because the query involves three tables (two large ones), so JOIN the three tables is very slow.

Then I split the SQL query to three queries. It improves the efficiency (for small dataset). But for large dataset, because the PHP program runs the three queries one by one, and processes the result after each, there will be 30 second timeout (by default). I don't want to remove this default setting.

To avoid timeout, I am also considering running the three query and returning the result to JS, and let client side to do processing.

Is there other way to do that?

**add**

Basically, I want three output, `title`, `extviews`, `allviews`, for each item, `WHERE extviews>somevalue`. `title` is from one small table, `extviews` and `allviews` are aggregated from two different large tables. I have all the fields indexed, but joining the two big tables still requires a long time.

So I first aggregate one table to get `extviews` for each item, and also a list of item `id`. The results are organized as an array for JSON output to JS. Then using the list of `id`, I get the `title` for each item, and aggregate the other table to get `allviews`. Then I update the array with the new results.

Comment: That is a horrible idea. It is your job to build efficient queries / applications, and your job to scale efficiently. Don't put the work on the user's shoulders, or they will not user your software. You should edit this question to show what your queries / dbs are setup as, and tell us how you've optimized them so far.

Comment: Are the queries repetitive?  In other words, can you cache the results so you don't have to perform the expensive queries, you can just load the data from a static cache file?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the tables you are querying?

Comment: "the PHP program runs the three queries one by one" - Surely you would rather make 3 requests and get the data in 3 parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your mysql server is really overloaded, it's usually quickier to use joins. I guess you've already defined indexes on your tables? (for fields used in join condition & where clauses)
Doing the processing on the client side might also be a problem, since you'll have to send a lot of data in order to do the join...

Edit:
If all "easy" optimisation is done, then you have 2 choices... The one you just described (doing it on client size, if it's possible - what is the size (in bytes) of the json arrays you send to the client?)
Your other choice is to do the processing in the background (via cron) & cache somehow the results.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated by other people responding to your post, you should give us an idea of the structure of your three tables and the intent of each.  Based upon that information, you may be able to get significant performance improvements by optimizing your database structure.  To make it easier to understand, let's assume that someone had a website running off an intelligently designed database.  I could easily make that application perform ten times worse solely by modifying the structure of the database.

Now, maybe there's some reason why you need to have three distinct tables, but I can't make that judgment without knowing what the fields in the database are, what you're aggregating, and what your web application is doing in the first place.  Is it read heavy or write heavy?  The solution may be as simple as denormalizing your database so that you don't need to use any joins.

I can say from a cursory glance at your description of what you're doing, that this application can't possibly scale efficiently and that you really need to reconsider your design.  The first warning sign for me is the fact that you stated that one of the joins is just to link the title to two other tables.  To me, being forced to do a join just to get a title of an object seems indicative of over-normalization.  Some data redundancy is not necessarily a bad thing, and in some situations it's absolutely mandatory.  Also, you say that you have two large tables that you use aggregate functions on and then join everything together.  I can tell you right now that you're going to run into some serious performance issues if every hit to your application involves using a triple join and two aggregate functions, I'm assuming count.

Ultimately, we'll be able to give you a better response once you provide more information as to what you're trying to accomplish, and the general structure of the database you set up for it.